# Magento 2 change price for each store view

Tags: magento, store, price

Can anybody help me how to edit price for each store view in magento 2?
I want to change Store->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Price from global to store view

Comment: you can't set price for store view you can only set price for website level only

Answer (score 2):

[Ref link](https://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/Set-different-prices-for-the-same-products-in-each-store-view/td-p/36213)

You can set price per website basis.

you need to go to **System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog** Price Scope.

Then in the tab "Price", set price scope to "Website" instead of global.

Different price for store view, many extension available. Here is some example:

1. https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-view-pricing.html
2. http://bsscommerce.com/magento-multistore-pricing.html

Comment: i don't want to buy the extension. I want an idea how to do that

Comment: than make a attribute in admin custom_price and use that price in frontend you can also update product original price with this one ..

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you Store View Price Scope extension from ecombricks. This extension author was the first who wrote Store View Pricing module for M1.

This extension supports all product types and base currency store view scope. Also, you can find the full set of store view scope modules there.